# Which is the intersection?

Tags: measure-theory

I got stuck at the following exercise. Could you give m a hint?

We have the increasing sets $A_n=\{n,n+1,n+2, \dots \}$.

To what is the intersection of the sets $$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$ equal ??

$$$$

For some values of n it is as followed $A_1=\{1,2,3,...\}, A_2=\{2,3...\}, A_3=\{3,...\}$

But how can I find the intersection when n tends to infinity??

Comment: intersection will be $\phi$

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is in the intersection, then $x \in A_n$ for all $n$, hence $x \geq n$ for all $n$.

Comment: The tag "set-theory", in my opinion, would be more suitable for this question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose

$$x\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\iff x\in A_n\;,\;\;\forall\;n\in\Bbb N\iff x\ge n\;,\;\;\forall\;n\in\Bbb N$$

and since the natural numbers are unbounded the above means the intersection is $\;\emptyset\;$

Answer (score 2):

Think about this: for every $n$, there exist an element in $A_{n}$ which doesn't belong to $A_{n+1}$. Considering $n \to \infty$, we can say that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection will be $\phi$, if possible let some $j\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $j\in \bigcap{A_n}$ then this implies $j\in A_{j+1}$ but this is not true